# Is replacing the map variable with a new map object thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, go

I don't think it thread-safe because map object is larger than a machine word, and Golang has no guarantee it's thead-safe. But when I run the demo code with `go run -race main.go`, it never reports errors. It might be the reason that ThreadSanitizer depends on runtime checking and assigning operation is hard to meet the thread unsafe condition.

Here is the sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var m = make(map[int]bool)

func Read() {
    for {
        for k := range m {
            fmt.Println(k)
        }
    }
}

func Replace() {
    for {
        newM := make(map[int]bool, 10)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            newM[i] = false
        }
        m = newM
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go Read()
    go Replace()

    <-c
}
```

So how could I modify the code to trigger the concurrent error? Or maybe I am wrong and the code is thread-safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things to note here:

```
        for k := range m {
```

Range expression is evaluated once at the beginning of the for loop. So this operation will read `m` once (note that this means if the code in the loop reassigns `m`, the loop will continue to iterate through the original `m`, but if new elements are added or elements are removed from `m`, those will be detected by the loop), and the loop itself will call `fmt.Println`, which consumes most of the execution time in that goroutine. If you want to catch the race, remove that.

Second, you don't really need to initialize the second map.

And when you do these things and run the race detector, it may catch the data race. In my case, it did.

The race detector complains about a race when it detects one. Because of that, if it reports a race, then there is a race. If it doesn't report one, that doesn't mean there isn't a race.

In my platform, a map variable itself is actually the same size as a machine word: it is simply a pointer to the map structure. So, the write to a map variable is actually atomic, that is, you would not see a partially-assigned map in this platform. However, that doesn't prevent the race, because there are no guarantees on when the other goroutine will see that memory write.

In short, there is a race. It is not because of the size of the map variable. To fix, use a mutex.

Comment: Thanks, after I remove the `fmt.Println`, it does report a warning. As you said, use a mutex. Thank you.

Comment: _"Range expression is evaluated once at the beginning of the for loop"_ is not technically correct. New values in the map _may_ appear during iteration, which implies that the map will be re-read in each iteration. This isn't much different from slices, where the slice expression will be evaluated once at the start, but each individual value must be read separately from the slice during iteration.

Comment: @JimB, The map variable is read only once, not the contents of the map. https://go.dev/play/p/vJfeKWo6gRH

Comment: True, the map variable is read once, and that applies when replacing the entire map. I guess I was concerned that people might take that as the map _and it's contents_ are evaluated once -- so I take that back, you are "technically correct", but I wanted to make sure it wasn't misleading at all ;)

Comment: @JimB, I see your point. I added an explanation, I hope that doesn't make it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is replacing the map variable with a new map object thread-safe?

No, It's unsafe.

What can you do to make it safe?

1. add some **lock control** in [sync](https://pkg.go.dev/sync) (like [sync.RWMutex](https://pkg.go.dev/sync@go1.19#)), here is a rough implementation from your code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type safeMap struct {
    rwLock sync.RWMutex
    m      map[int]bool
}

var safem = safeMap{
    m: make(map[int]bool),
}

func Read() {
    for {
        safem.rwLock.RLock()
        for k := range safem.m {
            fmt.Println(k)
        }
        safem.rwLock.RUnlock()
    }
}

func Replace() {
    for {
        newM := make(map[int]bool, 10)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            newM[i] = false
        }
        safem.rwLock.Lock()
        safem.m = newM
        safem.rwLock.Unlock()
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go Read()
    go Replace()

    <-c
}
```

2. use [sync.Map](https://pkg.go.dev/sync@go1.19#Map)

> Map is like a Go map[interface{}]interface{} but is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or coordination. Loads, stores, and deletes run in amortized constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question. I asked this question last year, but it was deleted by the community because they felt that if it triggered a data race report, they should use Mutex without discussion. However, in some scenarios, the performance impact needs to be considered, and various tricks are inevitably used in actual work. So this is worth discussing. Now I have the answer, [This answer is translated from my Chinese article](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000044278009).

## Scenes

This problem only applies to a few cases. For example, for a once-write-multiple-read Map, you can understand it as a "read-only" Map. If you replace it, whether with a lock or without a lock, the expected behavior is that the old Map is before the replacement and the new Map is after the replacement. At the moment of replacement, the old and new Maps exist at the same time. This is inevitable and natural. **So the only thing that needs to be discussed is, will not using a lock cause a panic or read erroneous data that does not exist?**

## TL;DR:

From a low-level perspective, on most processor architectures and the known versions of Go, overwriting a map is thread-safe if the operation does not exceed the size of a machine word. This is much like IB(Implementation-defined Behavior) in C/C++. However, Go's official stance does not encourage this practice. According to them, for data races, one should adopt macro-level serialization measures to ensure program safety. Consequently, any variable undergoing concurrent read and write at a macro level will generate a data race warning.

## Detailed Explanation:

Firstly, many developers think of a map as a hmap struct. However, strictly speaking, this is not the case. More precisely, a map is just a pointer to an hmap. Therefore, the size of a map does not exceed a machine word length. `unsafe.Sizeof(map1)` displays 4 bytes on 32-bit systems and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.

Moreover, you mentioned machine word length. It's essential to understand that, for assignments not exceeding the machine word length, most CPUs can execute them using just one instruction. So, how many instructions are required to perform an assignment operation on a map?

Let's consider this program. Line numbers are on the left. To ensure accuracy, we perform the assignment to m1 twice, as I'll explain shortly.

```golang
     1  package main
     2
     3  func main() {
     4          m1 := make(map[int]int, 20)
     5          m2 := make(map[int]int, 20)
     6          m1 = m2
     7          m1 = m2
     8          _ = m1
     9  }
```

Generate Go assembly code from the source:

```bash
go build -gcflags="-S -N -l" main.go 1> goasm.txt 2>&1
```

We can observe from the Go assembly code that only one Go assembly statement is utilized in line 6. However, line 7 involves two statements. It's important to note that both of these statements merely involve reading from and writing to registers—transferring data from memory to registers and then from registers back to memory. There's no intermediate state in this process because a core register cannot be overwritten by another core. Therefore, the fundamental operation comprises only one step: copying the value from the register to memory, denoted as `MOV REG MEM`.

Since Go assembly statements are pseudo-assembly and designed to compile across various hardware platforms, we directly disassemble the code:

```bash
objdump -S -d main > objdump.txt
```

On an amd64 Linux machine, the disassembly results show that the core operation is writing the register's value to memory:

```
    m1 = m2
  4576f0:   48 89 44 24 20          mov    %rax,0x20(%rsp)
    m1 = m2
  4576f5:   48 8b 54 24 18          mov    0x18(%rsp),%rdx
  4576fa:   48 89 54 24 20          mov    %rdx,0x20(%rsp)
```

## So, question 2: Are `MOV` operations atomic?

Yes, on most contemporary architectures, memory-aligned, not exceeding the machine word length `MOV` operations are atomic.

Refer to [The Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem), [Go Size and alignment guarantees](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees), [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html).

> Otherwise, a read r of a memory location x that is not larger than a machine word must observe some write w such that r does not happen before w and there is no write w' such that w happens before w' and w' happens before r. That is, each read must observe a value written by a preceding or concurrent write.

This statement might be cryptic, but the essence is that each read or write not exceeding the word length is complete and atomic, without a half-read or half-write scenario.

> The following minimal alignment properties are guaranteed:
>
> ```
> 1. For a variable x of any type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is at least 1.
> 2. For a variable x of struct type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the largest of all the values unsafe.Alignof(x.f) for each field f of x, but at least 1.
> 3. For a variable x of array type: unsafe.Alignof(x) is the same as the alignment of a variable of the array's element type.
> ```
>
> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

Go ensures certain alignment properties for variables in memory.

> 8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations
> The Intel486 processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following basic memory operations will
> always be carried out atomically:
>
> - Reading or writing a byte
> - Reading or writing a word aligned on a 16-bit boundary
> - Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary
>   The Pentium processor (and newer processors since) guarantees that the following additional memory operations
>   will always be carried out atomically:
> - Reading or writing a quadword aligned on a 64-bit boundary
> - 16-bit accesses to uncached memory locations that fit within a 32-bit data bus
>   The P6 family processors (and newer processors since) guarantee that the following additional memory operation
>   will always be carried out atomically:
> - Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache line

The Intel development manual guarantees that on most Intel processors, atomic operations are ensured for reading and writing operations not exceeding 64 bits in size.

Therefore, the answer is YES. On most processor architectures and known versions of Go, overwriting a map concurrently, as long as the operation does not exceed the machine word length. However, it's important to note that while this practice is feasible, the Go team does not encourage it. They caution:

> Go programmers writing data-race-free programs can rely on sequentially consistent execution of those programs, just as in essentially all other modern programming languages.
>
> When it comes to programs with races, both programmers and compilers should remember the advice: don't be clever.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to trigger a warning, modifying the Replace function a bit.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var m = make(map[int]bool)

func Read() {
    for {
        for k, v := range m {
            fmt.Println(k, v)
        }
    }
}

func Replace(flag bool) {
    for {
        newM := make(map[int]bool, 10)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            newM[i] = flag
        }
        m = newM
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go Read()
    go Replace(false)
    go Replace(true)

    <-c
}
```

As pointed out by @Burak Serdar, the reason for not detecting race might be due to `fmt.Println()` taking most of the execution time.